# Repeat a phrase in Latex throughout document

Tags: latex

I would like to set a reference a phrase in the beginning of a Latex document, such that I can reference later in the document and it will insert my phrase.

Purpose is to create a cover letter template that is personalized to each company. Later I can change only the reference phrase and Latex will do the rest, changing the name of company throughout the document.

Such as,

```
\documentclass[]{letter}

\include{*company reference package*}

\ref{Company XYZ}{Manufacturing and Distribution Company of the Americas, Inc.}
\begin{document}

Dear \ref{Company XYZ}, I have heard it is great to work at \ref{Company XYZ}. As a member of \ref{Company XYZ}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use a `\newcommand`, like so:

```
\documentclass[]{letter}

\newcommand{\CompanyXYZ}{Manufacturing and Distribution Company of the Americas, Inc.}

\begin{document}

Dear \CompanyXYZ, I have heard it is great to work at \CompanyXYZ. As a member of \CompanyXYZ

\end{document}
```

[image]